# how set up expire time while saving data mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

there is a way to set ttl (expire time?) while saving the data in the db ?

i have this schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 255,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 2000,
    },
    discountprice: {
      type: Number,
      maxlength: 32,
      trim: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      trim: true,
    },
    photo: String,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

i would like to set up a expire date for each product while saving ...

how do i save the product :

```
var product = {
              name: item.title,
              description: item.description,
              photo: item.image,
              discountprice: item.deal_price.value,
              price: item.list_price.value,
            };
      let prodotto = new Product(product);
                  prodotto.save((err, prodotto) => {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    }
                  });
```

how can i set up exipire time here ?

Comment: Why don't you add simply add an  `expire time` to your `productSchema` ?

Comment: @AlexisG yes but in that way i have to create a script or manually delete expired one's

Comment: Yes. There is no automated way to do this with mongodb. We will have to make a cron job or something similar

Comment: @AlexisG  thought ttl was for that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to add the expiration date to your model then simply pass the expiration as a variable in your product object.

```
var product = {
          name: item.title,
          description: item.description,
          photo: item.image,
          discountprice: item.deal_price.value,
          price: item.list_price.value,
          expiration: <some_value/variable> 
   };
```

Comment: yes, but in this way i have to delete manully or throught a script delete expired ones?